# Torch7 installation issues on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I was following the steps outlined in this post http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html. When I execute `./install.sh` I get the following warning and error:

```
Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21
cmake: /home/shree/anaconda2/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by cmake)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/shree/anaconda2/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
```

and repetition of same warning and, followed by the error:

```
/home/shree/torch/install/bin/luajit: symbol lookup error: /home/shree/anaconda2/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
Installing common Lua packages
/home/shree/torch/install/bin/luajit: symbol lookup error: /home/shree/anaconda2/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

and repetition of the same.

How do I resolve this ?

Other system related info: Ubuntu 14.04 + CUDA 7.5 + Anaconda (Python2.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the conflict seems to arise from the anaconda2 folder, I issued the following commands and it seems to be working now:

```
mv ~/anaconda2 ~/anaconda2_tmp
curl -sk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-luajit+torch | PREFIX=~/torch bash
```

And it appears to be working. Move the anaconda2 folder back after you are done.